# Installing Windows 10 as a guest operating system in VMware

Tags: windows-10, vmware-player

I am new to VMWare and I am trying to Installing Windows 10 as a guest on my Ubuntu 16.04.But log says that operating system was not found.
These are my

[image: settings]

Iso file is located in my /home directory of Linux filesystem.Is that OK or not?

I do not understand

[image: boot manager]

How to solve this?

Comment: click on edit VM setting and make sure you selected the ISO as DVD drive.

Comment: @magicandre1981 No,the point is that I can not install 5.4GB iso file on my 4.7GB DVD.Originally I have tried to used iso(placed inside /home...) but it seems that iso file is not recognized this way.

Comment: Just also try changing the boot order to CDROM First. Try both BIOS as well as EFI boot options. If you have any other bootable iSO e.g. Ubuntu or any rescue disk etc, also try configuring its ISO as boot disk just to rule out any issues with VMWare. There's some command I think isoinfo that shows if the ISO file has bootloader or not. Explore the exact Linux command and test the Windows 10 ISO.

Comment: I can mount large ISOs in VMware without any issues, but I use VMware on Windows host

Comment: Why are you using an unofficial Windows 10 ISO?

Comment: I used to , but I have solved it with the official version.